# Infer type of key based on key that is present in object

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a type that is used inside an array of inputs. I need type of Input.default to be inferred from the value of Input.key, so that it extends value of T[key]. I'm using typescript 5.0.4

```
type Input<T, T2 extends key of T> = {
    key: T2
    default: T[key] // type is inferred from value of key
}
```

E.g. if `T = { foo: string, bar: boolean }` and `key = 'bar'`, default must be type of boolean.
My needs:

```
var biz: Input<{ foo: string, bar: boolean }>[]

biz = [{
  key: "foo",
  default: "example"
},{
  key: "bar",
  default: true // No eror
},{
  key: "bar",
  default: "not boolean" // Errors
}]
```

As biz is an array, using typeparameters manually is not possible:

```
var biz: Input<{ foo: string, bar: boolean }, "bar">[] // Added "bar" as key

biz = [{
  key: "foo",
  default: "example" // Unwanted error. Type is based on T['bar'] not T['foo']
},{
  key: "bar",
  default: true // No eror
},{
  key: "bar",
  default: "not boolean" // Errors
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COnsider this example:

```js
type Shape = { foo: string, bar: boolean }

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type DataList<T> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof T]: {
    key: Prop,
    default: T[Prop]
  }
}>[]

type Result = DataList<Shape>


const biz: DataList<Shape> = [{
  key: "foo",
  default: "example" // Unwanted error. Type is based on T['bar'] not T['foo']
}, {
  key: "bar",
  default: true // No eror
}, {
  key: "bar",
  default: "not boolean" // Errors
}]
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoYXjN)

You need to iterate through Shape's keys and create new mapped type where `key` is a name of a key and `default` is a type.
See this:

```js
[Prop in keyof T]: {
    key: Prop,
    default: T[Prop]
  }
```

Then you need to wrap it into `Values` because you are interested in object values.

Just try to remove `Values` wrapper and check what you have

Comment: Thanks! This does work indeed. I or chatgpt did not think of using [Prop in keyof T].